# AppStore: upload app itself

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have to upload an app to the AppStore. I have uploaded the icon and screen shots, but there is no option to upload the app itself. How to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use Apple's "application loader" utility.

[Documentation here](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf)

Also note that this is now built in to the latest version of Xcode.

Comment: Where can i get application loader utility, can you please brief it in detail about it

Comment: I have downloaded application loader,while uploading my app through this i am getting the following error "app is not in valid location it should be at top level of archive"

Answer (score 1):

if you have XCode 4, do this

### iTunes Connect

1. Go to your ITunes Connect - where you enter App Detail
2. Click "View Detail"
3. See top right - "Ready to upload binary" - click it

### from your Xcode 4 - after setup all provision

1. Click Product -> Build For - Build for Archiving
2. Click Product -> Archive, it will open Organizer if nothing wrong
3. then click Submit...
4. follow the step